# mod_rewrite - rule according to url path

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am pretty weak at regex, and I need help with a mod_rewrite rule that does the following:

1. If the url is just the domain name: **xyz.com** -> go to index.php on directory a like so **xyz.com/a/index.php**
2. If the url includes a path: **xyz.com/abcde** -> go to index.php on directory b and change the path to a param like so: **xyz.com/b/index.php?id=abcde**

Both directories a and b are under the same root directory of course.

I managed to do number 2, but I have no idea how to include rule 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on
#--if url is just the domain name--#
#--rewrite to /a/index.php--#
RewriteRule ^$ /a/index.php [NC,L]

#--if it contains path--#
#--rewrite to /b/index.php?id=path
RewriteRule ^((?!b).+)$ /b/index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the:
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. 
WIth this configuration...

Comment: Do you have any other rules that can conflict with this?

Comment: Ok, I had a small typo in my htaccess, so now I do not get the same error, but only the second rule works, so when only the domain is used, it seems I do not go to the right index.php

Comment: are there any other rules above these rules?